# Cannot install Perl module in Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10 pro

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, perl, cpan

Not sure if I have run into a limitation of the Windows Ubuntu subsystem or something else, I've tried to install `sudo cpan install HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI` and it's throwing an error.

Running the same command on my native Ubuntu box and I get no error, it just installs.

```
$ sudo cpan install HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI

Reading '/home/joseph/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 30 Dec 2016 04:53:30 GMT
Running install for module 'HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI'
Running make for B/BP/BPS/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.51.tar.gz
Checksum for /home/joseph/.cpan/sources/authors/id/B/BP/BPS/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.51.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building B/BP/BPS/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.51.tar.gz

Cannot determine perl version info from lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm
Checking if your kit is complete...
Warning: the following files are missing in your kit:
        ex/sample_server
        inc/Module/Install.pm
        inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
        inc/Module/Install/Can.pm
        inc/Module/Install/Fetch.pm
        inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm
        inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
        inc/Module/Install/Win32.pm
        inc/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm
        lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm
        lib/HTTP/Server/Simple/CGI.pm
        lib/HTTP/Server/Simple/CGI/Environment.pm
        t/00smoke.t
        t/01live.t
        t/02pod.t
        t/03podcoverage.t
        t/04cgi.t
Please inform the author.
Writing Makefile for HTTP::Server::Simple
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  BPS/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.51.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Comment: I'm curious to see if anyone else has run into this issue. Just about to install Perl on Windows 10 myself.